# Change navigation based on route React router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm developing an application where I need two kinds of navigation bars. Well, the only thing that is going to be changing are the tabs. I have tried implementing it multiple ways, but nothing worked correctly (The problem is in routing)

Since the navbar gets rendered at top level, it doesn't have access to `useRouteMatch` url (it does, but it's always `/`), so I cannot figure out how to route correctly.

Example route:

`mypage.com/events/eventId/nested_route1`

But when I try to navigate to a different tab, it doesn't work as intended. It either pushes the routes onto each other or just doesn't work in some other way.

But i need just `mypage.com/events/eventId` as the base url. The navigation used to be in a component with exactly this route, so it worked. But now I need to change the location as specified.

How could I do this? I really have no clue... I could split and pop the url to get rid of the url, but then there'd be a problem if I was on the url `mypage.com/events/eventId` since it would pop the id.

Hope everything's clear and there's a way to solve my problem.